# ObjectDataProvider error finding prism classes and constructor parameters

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, objectdataprovider

Im trying to move the objects in my code-behind to my resources in XAML.

I want to move these objects

```
public partial class MainView : Window
{

    public EventAggregator IEA;
    public OrderViewModel order { get; set; }
    public MenuViewModel menu { get; set; }

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        IEA = new EventAggregator();

        order = new OrderViewModel(IEA);

        menu = new MenuViewModel(IEA);

    }

}
```

to here

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="IEA" d:IsDataSource="True" ObjectType="{x:Type Prism.Events:EventAggregator}"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="OVM" d:IsDataSource="True" ObjectType="{x:Type local:OrderViewModel}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="IEM"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MVM" d:IsDataSource="True" ObjectType="{x:Type local:MenuViewModel}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="IEM"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

But obviously im incorrectly referencing the EventAggregator class from Prism because i get the following error:

```
Error: 'Prism.Events' is an undeclared namespace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this works:

```
xmlns:prismEvents="clr-namespace:Prism.Events;assembly=Prism"


<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="IEA"
                        d:IsDataSource="True"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type prismEvents:EventAggregator}" />
```